# Search mutlidimensional array for a value and return key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array looking like this:

```
$user = array();
$user['albert']['email'] = 'an@example.com';
$user['albert']['someId'] = 'foo1';
$user['berta']['email'] = 'another@example.com';
$user['berta']['someId'] = 'bar2';
```

Now I want to find out which user has a certain `someId`. In this example I want to know who has the `someId` `bar2` and want the result `berta`. Is there a decent php function for this or would I have to create this on my own?

Comment: Not answering the question but why not have the `id` as the key of the array which would allow you to retrieve the data for a given record by simply using the key directly? e.g. `$username = $user[$id]['name']`. This seems the more logical way to structure your data and how a database is likely to index the records.

Comment: It's not an id like the pimary key of the user, it's more like the foreign key to something else. I tried to make that clear by naming it `someId` instead of `id`, possibly should have picked more concrete names for this example though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = 'bar2';

$result = array_filter(
  $user,
  function($u) use($id) { return $u['someId'] === $id; }
);

var_dump($result);
```

**Note:** this works in PHP 5.3+.
**Note 2:** there is no reason to use any version below nowadays.

Comment: @Veseliq true, but we are in 2013 ^^

Comment: Unless it's out of your control

Comment: Thanks, `array_filter()` seems to be a great function, a shame I missed it until now. One question: Why are you using `===` to compare? I know what it means and what the difference to `==` is, but my PHP days have been some years ago. Is it better (or safer) to always use `===` instead of `==` nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function it will return array of the matches.

```
function search_user($id) {
    $result = new array();
    foreach($user as $name => $user) {
       if ($user['someId'] == 'SOME_ID') {
           $result[] = $user;
       }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

if you always have one user with same id then you can just return one user, and throw exception otherwise

```
function search_user($id) {
    $result = new array();
    foreach($user as $name => $user) {
       if ($user['someId'] == 'SOME_ID') {
           $result[] = $user;
       }
    }
    switch (count($result)) {
        case 0: return null;
        case 1: return $result[0];
        default: throw new Exception("More then one user with the same id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in a function and `return $name`, would better fit his needs :)

Comment: @ironcito Updated, I return an array since there can be more then one user with the same ID (just in case).